# Update with SELECT and group without GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1093

I have a table like this (MySQL 5.0.x, MyISAM):

```
response{id, title, status, ...} (status: 1 new, 3 multi)
```

I would like to update the status from new (`status=1`) to multi (`status=3`) of all the responses if at least 20 have the same title.

I have this one, but it does not work :

```
UPDATE response SET status = 3 WHERE status = 1 AND title IN (
  SELECT title FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT(r.title) FROM response r WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM response spam WHERE spam.title = r.title LIMIT 20, 1)
   )
  as u)
```

Please note:

- I do the nested select to avoid the famous `You can't specify target table 'response' for update in FROM clause`
- I cannot use `GROUP BY` for performance reasons. The query cost with a solution using `LIMIT` is way better (but it is less readable).

**EDIT:**

- It is possible to do SELECT FROM an UPDATE target in MySQL. [See solution here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)
- The issue is on the data selected which is totaly wrong.
- The only solution I found which works is with a `GROUP BY`:

  ```
  UPDATE response SET status = 3
   WHERE status = 1 AND title IN (SELECT title 
                                    FROM (SELECT title 
                                            FROM response 
                                        GROUP BY title 
                                          HAVING COUNT(1) >= 20)
  ```

as derived_response)

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I don't really understand the second point. `GROUP BY` is going to be simpler and faster than the two subqueries with `EXISTS`.

Comment: In this case, with many records, the query cost of a `group by` is way higher. Even with the proper indexes. :(

Comment: if you add a filtering condition WHERE STATUS = 1 in the GROUP BY request the result should be faster (no need to recheck results where status was allready set to 3). I proposed below another slightly simpler variant (only one SELECT), but performances should be roughly the same.

Comment: @kriss: in my specific case, the result would not be the same. The already flagged records must also be counted. But they are not updated as they have the correct status. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write something straightforward like below

```
UPDATE `response`, (
  SELECT title, count(title) as count from `response`
     WHERE status = 1
     GROUP BY title
  ) AS tmp
  SET response.status = 3
  WHERE status = 1 AND response.title = tmp.title AND count >= 20;
```

Is using GROUP BY really that slow ? The solution you tried to implement looks like requesting again and again on the same table and should be way slower than using GROUP BY if it worked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Here are some results (1st value your query, 2nd "mine"): `**Created_tmp_tables** 3,1 - Handler_read_key 3415 0 - Handler_read_next: 3414,10003 - Handler_read_rnd: 393,0 - Handler_read_rnd_next: 788,2092544 - Handler_update: 3021,0 - Handler_write: 786 609 - Key_read_requests 259,746 -  **Last_query_cost**: 12396,162 - Select_scan: 1,2`

Comment: Looks like your request could be faster using a temporary table and setting and index on title. That should be enough to lower the Handler_read_round_next.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't like it when you try to UPDATE and SELECT from the same table in one query.  It has to do with locking priorities, etc.

Here's how I would solve this problem:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE response SET status = 3 ',
  'WHERE status = 1 AND title = ', QUOTE(title), ';') AS sql
FROM response
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20;
```

This query produces a series of UPDATE statements, with the quoted titles that deserve to be updated embedded.  Capture the result and run it as an SQL script.

I understand that `GROUP BY` in MySQL often incurs a temporary table, and this can be costly.  But is that a deal-breaker?  How frequently do you need to run this query?  Besides, any other solutions are likely to require a temporary table too.

---

I can think of one way to solve this problem without using `GROUP BY`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE titlecount (c INTEGER, title VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO titlecount (c, title)
 SELECT 1, title FROM response
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = c+1;

UPDATE response JOIN titlecount USING (title)
SET response.status = 3
WHERE response.status = 1 AND titlecount.c >= 20;
```

But this also uses a temporary table, which is why you try to avoid using `GROUP BY` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny peculiarity with MySQL - I can't think of a way to do it in a single statement (GROUP BY or no GROUP BY).

You could select the appropriate response rows into a temporary table first then do the update by selecting from that temp table.

Comment: Actually it is possible to do it in one query: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/ :)

Comment: @Toto - I think your case falls under the "Problems this doesn't avoid" situation.  I could be mistaken there though.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to use a temporary table:

```
create temporary table r_update (title varchar(10));

insert r_update
select title
  from response
group
    by title
having count(*) < 20;

update response r
left outer
  join r_update ru
    on ru.title = r.title
   set status = case when ru.title is null then 3 else 1;
```